# PHP 5.5 breaks empty() on SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, simplexml

I have recently updated my PHP from 5.3 to 5.5 and got this bug.

My XML is:

```
<search-response>
  ...
  ...
  <results-count>12345</results-count>
</search-response>
```

If I check for if $value is empty, it always is. While this worked in PHP 5.3. Did they change something in the `empty()` method?

```
$contents = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__). '/dummy.xml');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);

function xpath_val($source_xml, $argument_array) {

  $result = array();
  foreach($argument_array as $k => $v){
    $node = $source_xml->xpath($v[0]); 

    if (empty($node)) {
      $value = $node;
    } else {
      $value = $node[0];
    }

    if (empty($value)) {
      $nodeval = '';
    } else {
      $nodeval = strval($value);
    }

    echo $nodeval;
  }
}
$arr = array();
$arr['info'] = xpath_val($xml,array(
  'count'  => array('/search-response/results-count','integer')
));
var_dump($arr);
```

**edit**
return $nodeval; instead of echo $nodeval; gives:

```
array(1) {
  ["info"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Comment: Please show us your **full** and **real** code! How you get the xml in the variable and so on

Comment: The error log could be helpful, can you post it?

Comment: I posted the whole code

Comment: @henrik no error is generated, it simply adds a blank string to $nodeval

Comment: try return $nodeval instead of echo $nodeval;

Comment: @henrik I have added the array which $nodeval returns on the bottom of the main post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there was a change for the status of `empty` for a **SimpleXMLElement** beginning with 5.4. Before 5.4 the **SimpleXMLElement** representing the same element as from object access behaved the same with `empty($element)` as it did for those from the [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath) method result array.

Since PHP 5.4 the elements as xpath result objects are now always `true` when checked with `empty` (other accesses didn't change empty behaviour).

You're most likely not looking for `empty($value)` therefore but for `!strlen($value)`.

Take care that **SimpleXMLElement** comes with a lot of magic, `var_dump` and `print_r` for example don't work well with it. And also `empty` has some nuances.

If you test for the value of an *existing* **SimpleXMLElement**, cast it to string.

If you want to verify if the element exists, check that it's self-reference is not NULL.

There are also some bug-reports about the break on 5.3 -> 5. 4 version change with SimpleXML:

- [Bug #62203 - xpath doesn't return tag values](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62203) (Jun 2012)
- [Bug #62639 - XML structure broken](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62639) (Jul 2012)
- [Bug #62717 - BC: in PHP 5.4 empty() reports true for simplexmlelement](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=62717) (Aug 2012)